# Complexity of recursive solution to coin change

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

How do you go about analysing coin change recursive solution. i.e,
`T(N,K) = T(N,K-1) + T(N-1,K)` for K denominations that add up to amount N.

You can find the problem description and pseudo code here - http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change#Recursive_Formulation

Comment: The recursion in the question is different from what's written in the linked document. Please correct, or clarify what you mean.

Comment: There's a great analysis of this problem in the book [*Concrete Mathematics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics).

Comment: @darioSka You just bumped a years-old question to the front page just for adding a tag that doesn't even relate to the question? (This is about solving a recurrence; the underlying problem is not relevant.) Please don't do that!

Answer (score 2):

A general method for solving recurrences of this form is [generating functions](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). The exact solution also depends on the initial values. In your case, one possible solution is $T(n,k) = C 2^{n+k}$.